# The process of DNS lookup

Tags: dns, nameservers

I am a lot confused in this process of how DNS works. Every link is saying different things, which probably will be the same, but I cannot understand.
I'll try to put forward all what I know and have read. Please add on to this and correct wherever things are wrong.

1. Type www.example.com in your browser's address bar.
2. The browser sends a request to the system's OS to check in the hosts file.
3. The OS checks the hosts file if there exists a record having IP of example.com domain.
4. If the record exists, the IP address is returned to the browser. The browser then sends the request for the webpage directly to the IP address.
5. If the record in Step 3 doesn't exists, the browser gets a response from OS that the record is not found. The browser then asks the IP from DNS servers.
   (Is this correct? Browser gets a negative response and it sends requests to DNS servers or is it OS which directly requests DNS servers for IP once it knows hosts file doesnot contain the required record).
6. Now, my main doubt. What exactly are DNS servers? Are they what we call name-servers? Where do they reside? Who provides us with these name-servers? Browser sends them request or OS?

[This](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/what-is-domain-name-resolution/) post says DNS servers are configured on our systems and OS sends a request to these servers. 
Now, where do DNS resolvers come then. What are they doing. [This](https://icannwiki.org/Domain_Name_Resolvers) post says DNS resolvers are computers owned by ISPs  which does the translation. Then is the sequence of request like `Browser -> Hosts File-> DNS resolvers -> DNS servers` ? But who sends request to whom?

Please correct the above. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One through five in your list are correct. The browser asks your DNS resolver (your ISP's or whatever you put in your network settings). If the resolver doesn't know the answer it starts asking around.

I'll use `stackoverflow.com` as an example

1. The resolver asks the `root servers` and they answer with the `TLD servers` authoritative for `com`.
2. The resolver asks the `TLD servers` and they answer with the `name servers` configured for `stackoverflow.com` at the `domain registrar`.
3. The resolver asks the `name servers` and they respond with the `A record(s)`
4. The resolver caches the `A record` for a given time (either the `TTL` of the record or it has its own time overwriting the `TTL` given by the `name servers`) and when the resolver is asked again it returns what it has in the cache (unless the TTL has expired, then it starts asking again)

To summarize it looks like this:

`Browser -> Hosts File -> DNS resolver ->(rq*) Root servers -> TLD servers -> Name servers -> NS records`

- rq - recursive query

The `NS records` are asked if you want to open `www.stackoverflow.com`, they are like `name servers` (NS actually stands for `name server`), but for `sub domains`.

Comment: 1.) So, there isn't anything like one DNS server? It refers to various servers like TLD servers, name servers etc which are used in DNS resolution process? But, where do these servers reside? As one of the post (link I mentioned above in the question) said they are configured on our systems. 2.) DNS resolvers are residing on our ISP's side? 3.) Contacting DNS resolvers is browser's responsibility, not OS's?

Comment: 1) Yes, there is not just one DNS server (if it's down all the name resolution goes down). They are all over the worlds. 
 By `configured on our systems` the article means that in your system you put what resolver to be used by your PC, not that the server is located on your system. 2) The resolver can be your ISP's or it can be a public resolver like Google's `8.8.8.8`. 3) It's my understanding that the browser contacts the resolver (but I might be mistaken).

Comment: The name servers which respond with the A record are called authoritative name servers. They are supposed to answer queries for a specific domain. So does that mean each domain has a authoritative name server? Or one such server maintains information about various domains (I vote for this). If it's true, then which domains happens to be under one A-name server? I think it has to do something with zone.

Comment: Every domain has several authoritative name servers (one is enough, but for backup purposes at least 2 are required and some TLDs don't allow to have only 1). One server can be authoritative for as many domains it can handle, depending on the physical machine it is on. For a DNS server to know what DNS records a domain has there is a DNS zone (a simple text file with a special syntaxes), where all the records of the domain are written, separated file for each domain, on each DNS authoritative DNS server.

Comment: Refer to this post on my site here (https://deductionlearning.com/set-up-a-wordpress-site/introduction-to-domain-name-system/) . You may give it a read, it's all what you wrote above :)

Comment: Various nitpicks: 1) there are various sources of name to IP translations. On Unix system this is now controlled by `/etc/nsswitch.conf`  that describes which source to use and in which orders. hosts (files) and dns can be found here, among many other things (ldap, mdns, docker, etc.) 2) in general, all process asks the OS to do the resolution ; in some cases (browsers can be in that case for various reasons) some processes do DNS queries themselves 3) in DNS queries, the full name is requested at each stage, it is not label per label (at least until QNAME minimization everywhere)

Comment: Anyone can have a recursive nameserver: you can install it on your own computer; and this has various benefits. You can configure it to forward queries to your ISP nameserver or not. See `unbound` software for example.

Comment: And not all authoritative nameservers are backed internally by a text file for the zone content. Some can use a DB for example or various other dynamic systems (computing replies at the moment the query comes, without fixed predefined replies).

Answer (score 0):

Just to go into more details about DNS Lookup, here is my example:

- When you type www.google.com we actually call **www.google.com.** The **.** at the end represents the Root of the Internet’s namespace.
- Browser checks its own cache and if not found it asks OS for IP.
- OS then checks if the IP address is in memory (cache).
- If the browser and the operating system(cache) both don’t know the IP address, then the operating system is configured to ask the **Resolving Name Server (RNS)** for IP addresses it doesn’t know.
- RNS is the main workforce for the DNS lookup. It is configured both manually and automatically within your OS.
- The OS then queries the RNS for the IP. RNS may or may not have the IP in cache.
- The only thing that all the RNS must know is where to find the **Root Name Servers**, i.e., the . that appears after every url at the end.
- The Root Name Servers will reply with where to find the com name servers.
- The com name servers are the **Top Level Domain (TLD)** name servers.
- RNS then caches the info that it com from Root Name Servers and goes to TLD servers.
- The TLD name servers will reply by saying the location of google.com name servers. The next set of name servers are the **Authoritative Name Servers (ANS)**.
- RNS then caches the info that it com from TLD Name Servers and goes to ANS.
- ANS will now reply by saying that it knows the IP address of the URL.
- RNS will now save the IP address in its cache and then gives the reply to the OS.
- The OS then hands over the IP address to the browser.
- Then the browser makes a connection the IP address requesting a web page for the Url.

This entire cycle takes a fraction of a sec.

**Browser -> OS -> DNS Lookup -> RNS -> Root Name Server -> TLD -> ANS -> RNS -> OS -> Browser**